# Codeigniter default_controlller and pagination

Tags: codeigniter

I get 404 page when i go to any page

Routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";    
$route['default_controller/page/(:any)'] = 'home/$1';
```

Controller (home.php)

```
public function index($ppage=1)
    {
$this->load->library('pagination');
            $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
            $config['uri_segment'] = 2;

            $config['num_links'] = 5;
            $config['base_url'] = 'http://www.test.com/page/';

            $config['first_url'] = 'http://www.test.com/page/1';

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
}
```

When i go to the URL `http://www.test.com/page/1` or `http://www.test.com/page/2` i get 404 no found.  Where did i go wrong with this line?

```
$route['default_controller/page/(:any)'] = 'home/$1';
```

Comment: try this $route['page/(:any)'] = 'home/index/$1';

Answer (score 0):

Default controller isn't a variable:

```
$route['home/page/(:any)'] = 'home/$1';
```

or if that doesn't work:

```
$route['page/(:any)'] = 'home/$1';
```

Kindof a weird approach imo.